# Auto-import all *.scss in ReactJS project

Tags: reactjs, sass

Is there any way to import all _*.scss files to main App.scss file in React project? As I have separate folder for each component, I want to avoid typing

```
@import './components/UI/button';
@import './components/UI/menu';
@import './components/Forms/textInput';
```

What would be perfect is a working code like this:

```
@import './components/*';
```

I'm aware of order problem, I doesn't affect my css, files can be imported randomly.

Comment: is there a reason why you cannot import styles in appropriate components that use those styles? that approach would ensure there is no unused code(actually, file with code) injected. Also importing the same file for several times does not mean duplicating code in bundle. and finally typically it means much more flexibility to change the project structure

Comment: Until now I did that - in each component folder like /component/Button/ I had Button.js and Button.css imported by simple import './Button.css'. Someone told me that is good practice to use SASS in React projects and thats why I'm wondering how to implement it without too much typing. To be honest I think css with css-variables is just fine for React.

Comment: actually you can make `import './style.scss'` just like you are importing css. all you need is webpack [to be configured accordingly](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader)

Comment: Similar setup for how you were importing CSS. Instead, as skyboyer mentions, create a single `styles.scss` or `index.scss` that sits at the root of the `styles` folder and it imports all of your partials (these partials should contain styles that will be shared and used by many different components). Then, from a component-level scss file you would simply import that single stylesheet file (like importing a component). In addition, you'd have a `globals.scss` file that imports any static assets.

Comment: A more up and coming popular approach is `styled-components`, which aims to contain all things app related to reusable components in JS files: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components

Comment: I also love this feature. if there is. in react. that is not complex

Answer (score 0):

The [glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) package will do it if you really wanted. I would advise against it though, including a sass file directly in the component is more efficient but mostly because order matters in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can create file `_index.scss` in `components` directory and import all files from the subdirectories. After you can import writing `@import './components/index';` or `@import './components';`